# Sequence of finite dimensional subspace of a separable Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

This question is from an online course. I am not sure how to approach the problem.

> Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with a norm defined by the inner product. Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $H$ such that $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ in $H$. Then let $(V_i)$ be an increasing sequence of finite dimensional subspaces of $H$, $V_1\subset V_2\subset V_3\ldots\subset V_i\subset\ldots$ such that $\bigcup_iV_i$ is dense in $H$. Prove that
>
> i) $P_i(x)\to x$ for $i\to\infty$
>
> ii) $\forall i,P_i(x_n)\to P_i(x)$ for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: For (i), prove it first for $V:=\bigcup_{j\geq 1} V_j$ and use the fact that $\sup_i \Vert P_i\Vert<\infty$. For (ii), write an explicit formula for $P_i(x)$, using an orthonormal basis of $V_i$.

Comment: I meant: "prove it first for $x\in V$".

Comment: @Etienne I've done this for ii) : A sequence $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ if $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ for a bounded linear functional $f$ on $H$. $P_i$ is a bounded linear functional, so $P_i(x_n)\to P_i(x)$ as $n\to\infty$. Could you please help me in i)?

Comment: Be careful: $P_i$ is not a linear *functional*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Let us show that $P_i(z)\to z$ for every $z\in V$.

First, assume that $z\in V:=\bigcup_{i\geq 1} V_i$. Then $z\in V_{i_0}$ for some $i_0$, and since the sequence $(V_i)$ is increasing, $z\in V_i$ for all $i\geq i_0$. So $P_i(z)=z$ for all $i\geq i_0$, and the result is true in this case.

Now, let $z\in H$ be arbitrary, and let $\varepsilon >0$. Since $V$ is dense in $H$, one can find $z'\in V$ such that $\Vert z'-z\Vert<\varepsilon$; and since $P_i(z')\to z'$ by the first case, one can find $I$ such that $\Vert P_i(z')-z'\Vert<\varepsilon$ for all $i\geq I$. Since $\Vert P_i\Vert =1$, it follows that for all $i\geq I$, we have $$\Vert P_i(z)-z\Vert\leq \Vert P_i(z-z')\Vert +\Vert P_i(z')-z'\Vert+\Vert z'-z\Vert<3\varepsilon\, .$$
 Hence, $P_i(z)\to z$.

(ii) Let us fix $i$, and let $(e_1,\dots ,e_K)$ be an orthonormal basis of $V_i$. Then 
$$P_i(x_n)=\sum_{k=1}^K \langle x_n,e_k\rangle\, e_k $$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Since $\langle x_n,e_k\rangle\to \langle x,e_k\rangle$ for $k=1,\dots ,K$ as $n\to\infty$, it follows that $P_i(x_n)\to \sum_{k=1}^K \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k=P_i(x)$.